# Categories not appearing in correct order in top menu

Tags: magento2, topmenu

For some reason, certain categories don't display in the correct order in the top category menu, but instead appear after the list of the other categories. Any thoughts?

I've double-checked store view, etc, and have reindexed/cleared the cache to death.

Edit: by "correct order" I mean the order I've set in the backend by clicking and dragging.

Answer (score 1):

I think by default they are ordered based on their category ID. If you wanna arrange it alphabetically you can reorder it in admin side (catalog > categories) by dragging.

Comment: I've done that, and it works for the bulk of the categories, but for some reason there's a handful of categories that aren't ordered correctly.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on that? Reordering by dragging on admin side, clearing cache and re-indexing usually works.

Comment: Man, yeah, I'm not really sure what would be helpful -- apologies for the lack of info. I usually don't have any problems just reordering/clearing cache/reindexing/etc, but for some reason this just isn't working.